# why the result is different between cpu and gpu?

Tags: cuda, fortran

This is my code running on GPU

```
tid=threadidx%x
bid=blockidx%x
bdim=blockdim%x

isec = mesh_sec_1(lev)+bid-1
if (isec .le. mesh_sec_0(lev)) then
    if(.not.  sec_is_int(isec))  return

    do iele = tid, sec_n_ele(isec), bdim

        idx =  n_ele_idx(isec)+iele

        u(1:5)  =   fv_u(1:5,idx)
        u(6  )  =   fv_t(    idx)
        g       =  0.0d0
        do j=  sec_iA_ls(idx), sec_iA_ls(idx+1)-1
            ss  =   sec_jA_ls(1,j)
            ee  =   sec_jA_ls(2,j)
            tem =   n_ele_idx(ss)+ee
            du(1:5) =  fv_u(1:5, n_ele_idx(ss)+ee)-u(1:5)
            du(6  ) =  fv_t(     n_ele_idx(ss)+ee)-u(6  )
            coe(1:3) = sec_coe_ls(1:3,j)
            do k=1,6
                g(1:3,k)=g(1:3,k)+du(k)*sec_coe_ls(1:3,j)
            end do
        end do
        do j=1,6
        do i=1,3
            fv_gra(i+(j-1)*3,idx)=g(i,j)
        end do
        end do
    end do
end if
```

and next is my code running on CPU

```
    do isec = h_mesh_sec_1(lev),h_mesh_sec_0(lev)
    if(.not. h_sec_is_int(isec))  cycle
    do iele=1,h_sec_n_ele(isec)

        idx = h_n_ele_idx(isec)+iele

        u(1:5)  =  h_fv_u(1:5,idx)
        u(6  )  =  h_fv_t(    idx)
        g       =  0.0d0
        do j= h_sec_iA_ls(idx),h_sec_iA_ls(idx+1)-1
            ss  =  h_sec_jA_ls(1,j)
            ee  =  h_sec_jA_ls(2,j)
            du(1:5) =  h_fv_u(1:5,h_n_ele_idx(ss)+ee)-u(1:5)
            du(6  ) =  h_fv_t(    h_n_ele_idx(ss)+ee)-u(6  )
            do k=1,6
                g(1:3,k)= g(1:3,k) + du(k)*h_sec_coe_ls(1:3,j)
            end do
        end do
        do j=1,6
        do i=1,3
            h_fv_gra(i+(j-1)*3,idx) = g(i,j)
        enddo
        enddo

    end do
end do
```

The variable between h_* and * shows it belong to cpu and gpu separately.
The result is same at many points, but at some points they are a little different. I add the check code like this.

```
    do i =1,size(h_fv_gra,1)
    do j = 1,size(h_fv_gra,2)
        if(hd_fv_gra(i,j)-h_fv_gra(i,j) .ge. 1.0d-9) then
            print *,hd_fv_gra(i,j)-h_fv_gra(i,j),i,j
        end if
    end do
end do
```

The hd_* is a copy of the gpu result. we can see the difference:

1.8626451492309570E-009           13        14306

1.8626451492309570E-009           13        14465

1.8626451492309570E-009           13        14472

1.8626451492309570E-009           14        14128

1.8626451492309570E-009           14        14146

1.8626451492309570E-009           14        14150

1.8626451492309570E-009           14        14153

1.8626451492309570E-009           14        14155

1.8626451492309570E-009           14        14156

So I am confused about that. The precision of Cuda should not as large as this. Any reply will be welcomed.
In addition, I don't know how to print the variables in GPU codes, which can help me debug.

Comment: What are the actual values? Far larger than 1e-9? It may be just one bit difference due to float implementation. Is it significant?

Comment: the actual values is larger than 1e-9, about 1 million.

Comment: So 1e6 and difference of 1e-9 is pretty much the precision of doubles, which is around 15 digits. Most likely a one bit difference due to implementation

Comment: but the difference of other points is around 1e-16. and the difference of 1e-9 will result in obvious difference in my CFD simulation.

Comment: If this small difference is a problem for your CFD, something is very wrong with it.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that, in both double- and single-precision IEEE f-p numbers, `1.8626451492309570E-009==2^-29` and that there are no bits set in the significand -- it is all `0`s.

Comment: How coincidence! I see some other number except 1.8626451492309570E-009==2^-29 such as 2^-28 and 2^-27. And what do you mean by "it is all 0 s"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, calculation of `g` value most probably benefits from [Fused Multiply Add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply.E2.80.93add) (fma) optimization in CUDA.

```
g(1:3,k)=g(1:3,k)+du(k)*sec_coe_ls(1:3,j)
```

On the CPU side, this is not impossible but strongly depends on compiler choices (and the actual CPU running the code should it implement fma).

To enforce usage of separate multiply and add, you want to use intrinsics from CUDA, as defined [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__DOUBLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__DOUBLE), such as :

> `__device__ ​ double __dadd_rn ( double  x, double  y )` Add two floating point values in round-to-nearest-even mode.

and

> `__device__ ​ double __dmul_rn ( double  x, double  y )` Multiply two floating point values in round-to-nearest-even mode.

with a rounding mode identical to the one defined on CPU (it depends on the CPU architecture, whether it be Power or Intel x86 or other).

Alternate approach is to pass the `--fmad false` option to `ptxas` when compiling cuda, using the `--ptxas-options` option from nvcc detailed [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#axzz48Q9m4EQ1).

Comment: Thank you very much! when change my equation with __dadd_rd and __dmul_rd, the results between CPU and GPU are same. but I am curious whether the difference caused by FMA is normal or not, and does it play a important role in calculation?

Comment: In addition, do you know how to print the variables in GPU codes?

Comment: This is another question, and you could probably find an existing answer on SO, but you can simply call printf from a kernel.

Comment: FYI FMA should be giving more accurate results than splitting the computation into a multiply and an add.

Comment: @Jez, I believe the main point of Liu Hongbin is to have same results probably for non-regression testing. Accuracy of the results is a different topic.